# Is there a standard of rest in the universe?

Tags: special-relativity, cosmic-microwave-background, doppler-effect

If you measure the cosmic background radiation you will find that in any direction it is roughly the same. However, if you were to travel near the speed of light relative to the Earth in a particular direction then the cosmic background radiation would be observed to have different values based on what direction you measure it from. So, does the cosmic background radiation imply a standard of rest in the universe?

Comment: Duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25928/50583 and http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60860/50583

Comment: Thanks for finding those they answered my question very thoroughly.